# SQL subquery that gets sum of alias column

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am new to SQL and trying to create a subquery within my SQL statement that finds the sum of all the totals in my alias column. I'm a bit confused on how to format a subquery and every time I've tried it says that I am formatting it incorrectly.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ProductName, OD.UnitPrice, Quantity, OD.UnitPrice * Quantity AS total, SUM(SELECT(total)) AS finalTotal " +
            "FROM Products, [Order Details] AS OD " +
            "WHERE OD.ProductID = Products.ProductID AND orderID = @OrderID";
```

If I try the code above I get an error saying I have incorrect syntax near the SELECT statement. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please tag just one sql engine (correlating to the one you use). Please provide schema for your tables, and indicate the column name sum of which would be the `finalTotal`

Comment: Can you try the alias for Products too and normally table alias shall not have `AS`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Table aliases can have "as", but I don't think it's necessary in SQL server, and maybe not MySql.

Comment: Could you post the error on here as well? I'd suggest to try using JOIN and GROUP BY as the query would be easier to understand, however, the query cost could be higher than what you'd like.

Comment: @Nax.S All the error says is that I have incorrect syntax near the SELECT statement, there is no other info provided. I'll look into using JOIN and GROUP BY attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get sum for all the rows you can use `SUM` with `OVER`

```
SELECT *,SUM(total)OVER() AS finalTotal
FROM
  (
    SELECT P.ProductName, OD.UnitPrice, Quantity, OD.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity AS total
    FROM Products P
    JOIN [Order Details] OD ON OD.ProductID = Products.ProductID
    WHERE OD.orderID = @OrderID
  ) q
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here `SUM(SELECT(total))`, you cannot call select in this way, you have to specify `from` clause to make a subquery.

If you need to get the sum of all the rows (unit price * Quantity), Then:

```
SELECT Sum (UnitPrice * Quantity) AS total FROM Products
JOIN [Order Details] OD ON OD.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE OD.orderID = @OrderID
```

If you need to repeat that for the record set then:

```
SELECT *,SUM(total)OVER() AS OverAllTotal
FROM
  (
    SELECT P.ProductName, OD.UnitPrice, Quantity, OD.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity AS total
    FROM Products P
    JOIN [Order Details] OD ON OD.ProductID = Products.ProductID
    WHERE OD.orderID = @OrderID
  ) subQuery
```

Comment: In my code I have a column that displays the individual total for each order which is found by multiplying the unit price and the quantity. This is displayed in a row. At the end of the row I want to display the ultimate total, which adds up all of these individual totals that were found.

Comment: In this case you would have the same value repeated for every row. Because you are summing all the totals. Is that what you need?

Comment: Please, show example of the result set you want to return.

Comment: I mean that I have four unique totals found from multiplying the unit price and quantity, because they are four different orders returned from my query. I want to add up these 4 unique order totals into one final total at the end, if that makes sense.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Bzs8l86.png I want to find the sum of these totals.

Comment: Do you want the result set to looks similar to the picture? Or you want just the summation of total column?

Comment: The picture is the current result set I'm getting, so at the bottom I want to add a line that says what the summation of the total column is.

Comment: You can use one of the queries in my answer, the first one would do it. if you want to avoid executing the query twice, use the 2nd one, store the result set in a table varaiable. THen `Select top (1) OverallTotal from Temp_Table` to get that column. You are over complicating it.